# Get a parameter value from a GET request url. "TypeError: Cannot read property"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, url-parameters, get-request

I am just trying to get data out of the url route parameters from a get request. I'm pretty sure I had this working before, and I didn't change anything. Not sure what is going on.

I have been putting console.log calls all over the code, just to see what would show up. But they are never even called. Only the error message shows up.

I am using postman, and this is the get request I am making:

```
http://localhost:3333/users/accountidfind/1
```

This is the router from my index.ts file:

```
app.use('/users', userRouter);
```

This is the piece of code the error is coming from:

```
userRouter.get('/accountidfind/:account_id', async (req: Request, resp: Response) => {
  //console.log(`retrieving user with id ${(<any>+req).params.account_id}`);
  const account_id = (<any>+req).params.account_id;
```

This is the code as a whole:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
      import * as express from "express";
      import * as userDao from "../dao/user-dao";
      
userRouter.get('/accountidfind/:account_id', async (req: Request, resp: Response) => {
      //console.log(`retrieving user with id ${(<any>+req).params.account_id}`);
      const account_id = (<any>+req).params.account_id;
      
      try {
        const user = await userDao.getUserById(account_id);
        if (user !== undefined) {
          resp.json(user);
        } else {
          resp.sendStatus(400);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        resp.sendStatus(500);
      }
    });
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
 (node:9532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'account_id' of undefined
    at C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\routers\user-router.ts:95:41
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\routers\user-router.ts:27:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\routers\user-router.ts:23:12)
    at C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\routers\user-router.ts:94:85
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
(node:9532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 6)
```

I also do not understand how the error message is saying there is no catch block for the async function, when there is indeed a catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your conversion `(<any>+req)` which translates to `(+req)` which parses `req` as a number - thus you do not have `.params`

To rectify your issue replace `(<any>+req)` with `(req as any)` or `(<any>req)`

[Type Assertion Doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)